# Is this bijection from $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I've been doing some work over infinite sets and I was trying to establish a bijective mapping from $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ in order to prove that $|\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}|=|\mathbb{R}|$.

Because $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinte set, by the Axiom of Choice I have guaranteed that $\exists\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$, so we define $f$ as follows:
 \begin{align}f:\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z} &\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
x&\longmapsto f(x):=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x=a_0$}& \\
k+1, & \text{if $x=a_{3k+1}$}& \\
-k-1, & \text{if $x=a_{3k+2}$}& \quad \forall k\in\mathbb{N} \\
a_k, & \text{if $x=a_{3k+3}$}& \\
x, & \text{if $x\neq a_k$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

$f(a_{0})=0; \quad f(a_{3k+1})=\mathbb{Z}^{+}; \quad f(a_{3k+2})=\mathbb{Z}^{-}; \quad f(a_{3k+3})=\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$

The function is trivially bijective.

Is this mapping okay? Should I correct some formal aspects?

Comment: You don't need to invoke the Axiom of Choice here, as you can *produce* an infinite countable subset of $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$. For example, you can let $a_k = \frac{2k+1}{2}$.

Comment: I think your definition you want $f(x)=a_k$ when $x=a_{3k+3}$, rather than $k$. Otherwise, it's fine.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick.  you don't mean "for all $k \in N$".  You mean "if $x = ....$ for *some* $k \in N$".

Comment: I'm also not sure I'd say it is "trivially" bijective.  "trivially" does not mean "easily".  But now I'm *really* nitpicking.

Comment: An easier way to prove $|A|=|B|$, is to just find injective functions in both directions. It's often a lot easier than finding a bijection.

Comment: @Vsotvep and what injective function would you use from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$??

Comment: @Rober Any injective map from $\mathbb R$ to $(0,1)\subset\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Z$ will do, such as $\arctan(x)/\pi+\frac{1}{2}$ for example.

Comment: $ f(a_{3k+3})=\{a_k\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is incoherent.